# Get variation direct URL programmatically

Tags: woocommerce

Very simply put, I'd like to get the variation direct permalink, that is with the variation param, ie. with the `?pa_size=40` querystring appended to it. Is there such a WC method to get this directly?

I'll be check first `if ( is_type( 'variation' ) )`

I forgot to mention that I want that direct link **only** if the variable attribute is size, that is pa_size.